# Left/Right join table with itself

Tags: sql, left-join, rdbms

I have a table which contains all the active loans for every month (for example 2017_01, 2017_02, 2017_03, etc). As I don't have another table which contains the Non Active loans (the closed ones) I have to manipulate the same table to get the closed loans for every specific months.

I have tried RIGHT OUTER JOIN in order to get the loans which are part of the previous YEAR_MONTH and have a NULL value in the next month, but as the table is joining itself using the LOAN_NUMBER field as a key, I am not getting the desired results.

Any idea of what I can do?

Ps: In other cases I needed to do that I used the "WHERE NOT EXISTS" clause, but I had two different tables.

My query is:

```
SELECT DM07MD.LOAN_NUMBER, DM07MD2.LOAN_NUMBER AS L2
FROM [dbo].[DM_07MONTHLY_DATA] DM07MD
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[DM_07MONTHLY_DATA] DM07MD2
ON DM07MD.LOAN_NUMBER = DM07MD2.LOAN_NUMBER
AND DM07MD.YYYY_MM = '2017_01'

WHERE DM07MD.S90T01_CLIENT_SEGMENT IN ('PI', 'MICRO')
AND DM07MD.S90T01_IS_RESTRUCTURED = 1
AND DM07MD2.LOAN_NUMBER IS NULL
AND DM07MD.YYYY_MM = '2017_02'
```

Comment: Add the table structure,sample data and expected output in the question.

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: And tag the DBMS

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same by using exists,

```
 SELECT DM07MD.LOAN_NUMBER FROM [dbo].[DM_07MONTHLY_DATA] DM07MD where  DM07MD.YYYY_MM = '2017_02' and not exists 
( SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[DM_07MONTHLY_DATA] DM07MD2 where  DM07MD.YYYY_MM = '2017_01' and DM07MD.LOAN_NUMBER=DM07MD2.LOAN_NUMBER )
```

Comment: It executes successfully but it doesn't return the right number of rows :/

Comment: then change the condition inner and outer